# using the verb "blame"

Tags: verbs

> I am not to be blamed
>
> Many accidents were blamed on the snow
>
> be to blame
>
> If a ship sinks, the captain is to blame
>
> **The increase in crime is a sad reflection on our society
>
> The increase in crime is, sadly, to be blamed on our society**

I am wondering about how is the function of applying the verb *blame*, that is, I cannot differentiate when to use it as an *intransitive, or passive verb.*

Furthermore, I am wonder if the bold parts might mean the same thing or not.

Comment: this is a good question. +1. I'd prefer, *"...the captain is to be blamed"* but what you wrote is *not incorrect*.

Comment: A nice Q indeed. Think about it for 15 seconds, and you realize this question needs a very meticulous and delicate approach. But I have a hunch that the bold parts don't mean the same.

Comment: @MaulikV "he is to blame" is more often used than "he is to be blamed". I have written an answer for this kind of sentences. I couldn't help but the answer is a bit lengthy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *blame* is used to reflect *responsibility* for something.

To answer your question about the bolded sentences: **"The increase in crime is a sad reflection on our society,"** holds a nuance that suggests the crime is increasing because society is lacking in morals. There is no implied 'call to action' in that sentence.

In the second case: **The increase in crime is, sadly, to be blamed on our society,** the sentence uses the word *blame* which implies a sense of responsibility. Society is *responsible for* the crime, and it then follows that society is responsible to *do* something about the crime. This sentence creates a feeling of requiring action.

The word *blame* is always used transitively like the word "hit". You have to blame someone/something. Blame is used passively in writing, such as the examples that you mentioned. In modern American English, it is rarely used passively ("be to blame") in speech. It would be used with *be ~ing* instead:

> "What happened?"
>
> "They'**re blaming** the captain because the ship sank."
>
> "Oh! I thought they **were blaming** the ship company instead."

It is also possible to use *blame* actively, but it's quite rare. In fact, I can only think of it being used in a very direct way. *ie.* **"I blame** you/him/her." To which it would (typically) be unnatural to reply, "Why *do you blame* me/him/her?" You would have to respond, "Why **are you blaming** me/him/her?"

Answer (score 2):

As a learner I always had the problem with this kind of sentences, but never got the proper answer.

Let's consider the following two sentences -

> The film is expected to be released on coming Friday.
>
> The film is expected to release on coming Friday.

I have seen both sentences, but my logic said that the passive form is only possible as the film can't release itself. It has to be someone who will release the film.

But I was wrong. Both of the sentences are possible and correct. Of course the film can't release itself, but it needs someone to release the film. But to understand these two sentences we need to think of them from a different point of view.

In both the sentences the subject of the infinitive clause is not explicitly mentioned. We imagine the superordinate subject to be the subject of the infinite clause. But that is not always the case; if we imagine the subject of the infinitive clause, we can even think of an indefinite subject also. So here lies the secret.

> The film is expected to be released on coming Friday.

Here the implied subject of the infinitive clause is a superordinate subject. So we can re-write the sentence as the following, explicitly mentioning the superordinate subject as the subject of the infinitive clause -

> The film is expected for *it (the film)* to be released on coming Friday.

Now consider the other sentence -

> The film is expected to release on coming Friday.

Here the implied subject of the infinitive clause is not the superordinate subject, rather the implied subject of the infinitive clause is an indefinite subject. So we can re-write the sentence as the following, explicitly mentioning the indefinite subject as the subject of the infinitive clause -

> The film is expected for *others* to release on coming Friday.

Now coming to your sentences with *blame*.

> The captain is to be blamed.
>
> The captain is to blame.

Both of the sentences are correct. In the first sentence the implied subject of the infinitive clause is the superordinate subject (*he*), and in the second sentence the implied subject of the infinitive clause is the indefinite subject (*other*). Now re-writing both the sentences explicitly mentioning the subject of the infinitive clause -

> The captain is for *the captain* to be blamed.
>
> The captain is for *others* to blame.

Let's explain this aspect of grammar in details.

---

The structure **noun + infinitive** can express the idea of obligation.Active and passive infinitives are both possible.

> I have got **letters to write**.
>
> The **carpets to be cleaned** are in the garage.

If the subject of the clause is the person who has to do the action, active infinitives are used.

> I have got work **to do** (NOT *I have got work **to be done***)

If the subject of the clause is the person or the thing that the action is done to, passive infinitives are normally used after *be*.

> These sheets **are to be washed**. (NOT *These sheets **are to wash***)
>
> The form **is to be filled in** with blue ink. (NOT *This form **is to fill in** with blue ink*)
>
> The cleaning **is to be finished** by midday (NOT *...**is to finish**...)

Active infinitives are possible in a structure with *for* (explicitly mentioning the subject of the infinitive clause using *for*)

> This form is **for you to fill in**.

In other cases, active and passive infinitives are often both possible with the same meaning. (similar to your example sentences in your question)

> There is a lot of work **to do/to be done** [when the implied subject of the infinitive clause is **work**, only **to be done** is correct. When the implied subject of the infinitive clause is e.g. **others**, **to do** is only possible.]
>
> There are six letters **to post/to be posted**.
>
> Give me the names of the people **to contact/to be contacted**.
>
> The people **to interview/to be interviewed** are in the next room.

Consider the following sentence  -

> She write quickly enough *to finish the paper on time*.

The infinitive clause - *to finish the paper on time* - doesn't have a explicit subject, though it's understandable. We can re-write this sentence with a clear subject of the infinitive clause.

> She write quickly enough *for her to finish the paper on time*.

So the subject of the infinitive clause can be omitted or retained if t substitute for the superordinate subject. When there is no subject in the infinitive clause, it's identified with superordinate subject or with an indefinite subject.

There are cases when ambiguity arises as to which subject is implied. Whether the superordinate subject or an indefinite subject is implied is not clear.

> She is to young *to date*.[*...for her to date others*? or *...for others to date her...*?]

When the subject of the superordinate clause is agentive, it may be redundantly repeated.

> The knife is sharp enough for it (the knife) to carve the turkey.

Sometimes this optional redundancy is retained for emphasis purpose.

---

**What is an Indefinite Subject?**

Consider the following sentence -

> We me you leaving the room.

If we hear this sentence, we keep guessing who is leaving the room - you? we? or you and us both?

> We met you (*when you? we? were*) leaving the room.

With infinitive clause, a corresponding finite clause also enables one to identify an understood subject.

> I asked *to go* ~ I asked *if I could go*.
>
> I asked *him to go* ~ I asked *if he would go*.

When no referential link with the nominal can be discovered in the linguistic context, an indefinite subject may be inferred, or else the *'I'* of the speaker:

> The prospects are not very good, *to be candid* [...if I am to be candid']

In the above example the subject - *I* - is inferred, and so it's indefinite subject.

**What is a Superordinate Subject?**

The subject of a **superordinate clause** is called a **superordinate subject**.

A **Superordinate clause** in grammatical analysis is a term for a clause that contains another clause.

> It was raining *when I left home*.

The clause - *It was raining* - contains another clause - *when I left home*. So the clause - *It was raining* - is the superordinate clause of the subordinate - *when I left home*.

The subject of the superordinate clause is *it*, and so *it* is called superordinate subject.

**Agentive role -**

> Margaret is mowing the grass.

In this sentence *Margaret* is the subject, *mowing* is the verb and *grass* is the direct object of the verb.

The most typical semantic role of a subject in a clause that has a direct object is that of the **Agentive** participant: that is, the animate being instigating or causing the happening denoted by the verb.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, none of these are my answer at all.

Comment: @nima I know :) I was going to write an answer, but suddenly got something urgent to attend to, so had to leave this answer before finishing it off. I will complete it today.

Answer (score 0):

I will only try to answer your last question: No, the two bolded sentences are not equivalent. To say that something "is a sad reflection on" means only that a society in which such crimes happen is not to be admired. It does not say that the society itself was the cause of those crimes. The two sentences aim the same direction, but one goes much further in actually accusing society of causing increased crime.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, we must remember that the word "blame",  apart from being a noun, is only a transitive verb.  I don't think it's necessary to explain as to how to form the active and passive voice with this transitive verb as I feel the OP has a good knowledge of Engish.
I am sure his confusion is only because he thinks that "blame" is also an intransitive verb.

As a matter of fact, "be to blame" is an idiom, in which the word "blame" has been used as a noun.  You use this idiom when you say that someone/something is responsible for something bad or is at fault, for example, which driver was to blame for the accident. Hence, "be to blame" is more idiomatic than "to be blamed".

Please look up the word the idiom "be to blame" in The Free Dictionary, which uses blame in the idiom as a noun.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blame

As for two sentences about society, they convey the sense in different words.

Comment: In *he is to **blame***, the word -**blame** is a noun?