# Irregular conjugation of the verb "blame"

Tags: irregular-forms

Is it o.k. to conjugate the verb "blame" in this way?:

> I am to blame.
>
> You are to blame.
>
> He/She/It is to blame...and so on.

In order to tell someone themselves **blames** something on.

Comment: I think it's possible, but I can't think of any reason to do so. Why not, just say "I blame..". And maybe [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv103.shtml) could help.

Comment: This answer might help - https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46339/3463

Comment: Yes: that's fine. "Be" and a handful of other verbs take hollow _to_-infinitivals as complement, so we get "You are to blame __". The missing element is the object of the verb "blame" and is represented by gap, the meaning of which is recoverable from an antecedent. In this case, the antecedent is "you": We understand that "You are to blame you (yourself)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable to use the word **blame** in the way you described.

Saying a phrase like "I am to blame" or the other examples you provided means that the object of the phrase should or could be blamed by **anyone**.

For example, if you said:

> I blame myself.

This means that only the speaker is the one blaming themselves. Likewise in this example:

> Jim blames Susan.

Here Jim is the only person blaming Susan.  On the other hand:

> I am to blame.
>
> Susan is to blame.

This means that *I* or *Susan* can be reasonably blamed by *anyone*. It would be comparable to:

> I am *the person* to blame.

or

> I am *the one for people* to blame.

Comment: I'm not sure why you included ***the person*** in your penultimate example - whether present or not the implication is the speaker is telling his audience that ***they*** should blame ***him***. Pragmatically, we might well assume the speaker ***also blames himself***, but this might not be the case, and it's completely unaffected by including ***the person***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess I thought that would be illustrative, perhaps those weren't the best examples.